# .ssh/rc not called by ssh (do you have an idea why?)

Tags: ubuntu, ssh

I created a `rc` file in the `.ssh` folder, put a `750` chmod on it. My `rc` file is simply containing an echo (`echo 'hello world`). If I execute a ssh command like `ssh user@destination`, I never get the message `hello world`. Of course, I want later to replace this simple code with other actions to automatize my workflow. But I guess that my `rc` file is newer executed. Do you have an idea why ?

(before the echo instruction I already put `#!/bin/bash`)

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the contents of this rc file. It would also be helpful to run "ls -l" on the file so we can see the filesystem permissions of the file.

Comment: Try `chmod 700 ~/.ssh`.